# Prove that $3x+2y-2xy-2\geq0$ when $x,y\in[0.5,1)$?

Tags: inequality

I am looking for the proof that $3x+2y-2xy-2\geq0$ when $x,y\in[0.5,1)$. This seems to be true when plotted out. Is there a simple and elegant way to show this? Thanks.

Comment: Try finding the minima of the function $z = 3x + 2y - 2xy - 2$ which exists in the critical point (if any) or on the boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the LHS of inequality as $(3x+2y)(1-x)+3x^2-2$ , now see if you want to minimise this expression, $y$ will take it's minimum value as $1-x$ is positive, so minimum occurs at $y=0.5$ hence you are left with $3x+1-x-2 \geq 0 $ which is nothing but $x \geq 0.5$, which is true.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to

$$
1\geq (3-2y)(1-x)
$$

Since both $(3-2y)$ and $(1-x)$ are positive in the range, we just need to prove the inequality is valid when both $x$ and $y$ are mininum.